# How to keep an image full window, centred and responsive within ratio?

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, responsive-images

I am trying to figure out how this website [here](http://installed.co.nz/garage-carpet/)
has made the responsive header image that fills the window size onload and resizes with the window resize while still filling the window in it's original ratio.

This is what I have come up with so far but it is very glitchy...

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcraig/5z8d9sbk)

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#intro-background').height( $(window).height() );
    $('#intro-background img').height( $(window).height() );
    var imageRatio = (1900 / 1270); //Original image size

    $(window).resize(function() {
      $('#intro-background').height( $(window).height() );
      var windowRatio = $(window).width() / $(window).height();

      if(windowRatio != imageRatio) {

        if($('#intro-background img').width() < $(window).width()) {
            $('#intro-background img').width($(window).width());
            $('#intro-background img').height($(window).width() / imageRatio);
        } else if( $('#intro-background img').height() > $(window).height() ) {
            $('#intro-background img').height($(window).height());
            $('#intro-background img').width($(window).height() * imageRatio);  
        }

        if($('#intro-background img').height() < $(window).height()) {
          $('#intro-background img').height($(window).height());
          $('#intro-background img').width($(window).height() * imageRatio);
        }

      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I have updated the fiddle link to show not only the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they just run a script every second which does the calculation and then sets the height and width. In this case you are wisely using the window resize functionality within jQuery

Look at: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

In you fiddle you are resizing a div with $(window).resize
You can solve this solely by using CSS.
Remember that using javascript will be slower than using CSS.

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hzrjhy4/1/)
Hence the following in the CSS:

```
*, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I also removed the width and height from the #img id
Resizing now works perfectly

If you really would like te resize a image without setting an incorrect ratio you can look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a54zfxzd/1/) where I use real image to resize on the resize of the screen.

All you have to do there is:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = ($('#intro-background').width() / 4);    
    $('#img').css('height', height);
});
```

If you would like to keep your 100% height on a real image you can also set CSS to handle the image for you. Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88hrvxsw/2/) for that.

Here also you need to set *, html in the CSS and of course use background-size: cover;

See here:

```
*, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#img {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:red;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Try resize the window until it is about less than 100px tall. The width starts hopping about.

Comment: I will try it in a different browser, the fiddle I placed does work with a real image and no hopping around.

Comment: Your fiddle, is chrome at least, allows the container to become less than 100% height and thus restricting the size of the image. I have update my fiddle link. If you view it with all the code windows visible you should be able to recreated the width hopping I mentioned (red container becomes narrow exposing the yellow)

Comment: I can see the hopping, let me see if I can change that for you. 
Can you tell me why you need to have the 100% height? 
As you are using a DIV you can also do something else to keep the height 100% and the with flexible without doing a window resize

Comment: So @Beno I created several fiddles, basically showing options using CSS in stead of javascript for your solution. This is faster and works smooth so no glitches here.

Comment: Thank you! I have gone with your last fiddle. I really appreciate all the effort! =D

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, I will never use a code like yours for what you need, I mean there are a lot of stuff to consider, resolution, border, transition, carousel, mobile etc. I always used **[BACKSTRETCH](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)** it's easy, lite, and faster for this kind of stuff, or if you don't need to work with old browser, consider to use **CSS**

```
#myelement{
    background-size:cover
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have this which works pretty well

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcraig/vc3bjexu/1/)

```
function imageResize() {
var imageRatio = (1900 / 1270); //Original image size
if( $('#intro-background img').height() != $(window).height() ) {   
    $('#intro-background img').height( $(window).height() ).width( $(window).height() * imageRatio );
    if( $('#intro-background img').width() < $(window).width() ) {
        $('#intro-background img').width( $(window).width() ).height( $(window).width() / imageRatio );
    }
}}
imageResize(); // Called onLoad
$(window).resize(function() {
    imageResize();
});
```

Any suggestions of doing this a better way? I would also like the image to stay centred to the resizing container.